# How do you align page numbers 2 and 3?

Tags: vertical-alignment, page-numbering, fancyhdr

I am formatting a 115 page book. I have a really strange problem. Page numbers 2 and 3 are not horizontally aligned as you can see in the screenshot.

[image]

I have checked other page numbers and they are perfectly aligned. I am using the `fancyhdr` and the `geometry` with a `book` class.

I have tried adding and removing text from chapter 1, the results are the same.

What can I do to align those page numbers?

Here is code from the preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[
    top=0.5in,
    bottom=0.5in,
    inner=0.725in,
    outer=0.6in,
    headsep=0.15in,
    footskip=0.32in,
    includehead,
    includefoot,
    papersize={5.5in,8.5in}]{geometry}
    \fancypagestyle{plain}{
        \fancyhf{}
        \fancyfoot[C]{\scriptsize \thepage}
        \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
        \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}
```

I am also using OpenType fonts for the main body:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
    Ligatures=TeX,
    BoldFont=ACaslonPro-Semibold.otf,
    ItalicFont=ACaslonPro-Italic.otf,
    BoldItalicFont=ACaslonPro-SemiboldItalic.otf
    ]{ACaslonPro-Regular.otf}
```

Here is code from chapter 1:

```
\thispagestyle{plain}
\fancyhead[RO]{\small \it Chapter's Title}
\fancyhead[LE]{\small \it Author's Name}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\scriptsize \thepage}
```

Comment: How should we figure out from a figure only? You should show us the relevant document code which generates the pages above

Comment: The posted code is not compilable and might not even reproduce the behaviour. Write in your normal text `0123456789` to check if you are using a font with old-style figures.

Comment: The page numbers are at the top, not centered etc.

Comment: `\pagestyle{plain}`, not `\thispagestyle{plain}`. And please post a the whole code which compiled, not one fragment after another one at last!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a *clear* warning by `fancyhdr` about the `\headheight` being too small:

```
Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt): 
 Make it at least 13.59999pt.
 We now make it that large for the rest of the document.
 This may cause the page layout to be inconsistent, however.
```

---

Changing this accordingly to `head=14pt` as `geometry` option will solve the wrong alignment of the page numbers.
I've added a `\hrulefill` to show the alignment.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[
    top=0.5in,
    bottom=0.5in,
    inner=0.725in,
    outer=0.6in,
    headsep=0.15in,
    footskip=0.32in,
    includehead,
    includefoot,
    head=14pt,
    papersize={5.5in,8.5in}]{geometry}



\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
        \fancyhf{}
        \fancyfoot[C]{\scriptsize \thepage}
        \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
        \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
%\thispagestyle{plain}
\pagestyle{plain}
\fancyhead[RO]{\small \it Chapter's Title}
\fancyhead[LE]{\small \it Author's Name}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\scriptsize \thepage\hrulefill} % Remove \hrulefill later on


\blindtext[20]
\end{document}
```

[image]